# When I should use "into", "in", "by" and "through"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I never know when to use the terms "into", "in", "by" and "through".

For example:

- Context one: "Run this command __ Windows prompt"
- Context two: "Execute the command __ the menu option 'File -> Preferences' "

In this cases I should use "into", "in", "by" or "through"?
So when I should use each one of this terms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C1, use *at the* for natural wording; ie, “Run this command at the Windows prompt”.  Some people may speak of “*in* the Windows prompt”, by which they probably mean in a DOS window (so they should be saying “Run this command in a DOS window”, which is acceptable), but *at the* is more exact and more natural when referring to entering a command at a command prompt.

In C2, *[using](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/using#Verb)* or *[via](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/via#Preposition)* are better: “Execute the command using menu option ‘File->Preferences’” or “Execute the command via menu option ‘File->Preferences’”. Although *by* and *through* are possibilities in C2, neither is as good as either of  *using* or *via*.  (Disclaimer:  If I understand correctly, I'd say “Select menu option ‘File->Preferences’” instead of “Execute the command via menu option ‘File->Preferences’”, because I doubt you can actually execute commands via the `File` menu.)

Comment: You are correct. I just found Microsoft documentation using 'at' [Command-line tools must be run at the prompt of the Cmd.exe command interpreter].

Comment: Thanks a lot!  
About the final comment, I tried to adapt the context to make sense for the not developers readers.  
The original context was "Execute the command __via__ Ant".

Thanks again.